# Show that a simultaneous eigenfunction of $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ leads to a contradiction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, commutator, eigenvalue

It is easy to show via the Canonical Commutation Relation $ [\hat{x}, \hat{p}_x] = i\hbar $ that the existence of a simultaneous eigenfunction of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}_x$ leads to a contradiction, affirming the fact that if the operators don't commute, their observables can't be measured simultaneously.

In the same spirit I want to show via the non-commuting relation $ [\hat{L}_x, \hat{L}_y] = i\hbar \hat{L}_z $ for orbital angular momentum that the existence of a simultaneous eigenfunction of $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ also leads to a contradiction but I'm having some trouble.

The fundamental difference in these two commutators is that the former is a number and the latter is another operator, $i\hbar\hat{L}_z$. If I proceed by declaring that $\varphi$ is an eigenfunction of $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$:
$$ \hat{L}_x\varphi = L_x\varphi $$
$$ \hat{L}_y\varphi = L_y\varphi $$
then
$$ 0 = i\hbar\hat{L}_z\varphi $$
$$ \hat{L}_z \varphi = 0 $$
$ \hat{L}_z \varphi = 0 $ is satisfied if $\varphi$ is an eigenfunction of $\hat{L}_z$ with eigenvalue $L_z = 0$.

Thus it would seem that you **can** measure $L_x$ and $L_y$ simultaneously so long as $L_z = 0$? Now it would seem that all three are simultaneously measurable. Are there no contradictions so far? I've been told "this is only possible in the $L = 0$ state". So I guess what remains to be shown is that $L_x$ and $L_y$ must be zero as well, but no one has been able to show me why without using matrices, which is out of the scope of the introductory course I'm taking

Comment: There is a common eigenfunction, indeed. There should be some questions/answers regarding this here already.

Comment: In addition to $[\hat{L}_x, \hat{L}_y]=i\hbar\hat{L}_z$, you also have that $[\hat{L}_z, \hat{L}_x]=i\hbar\hat{L}_y$ and $[\hat{L}_y, \hat{L}_z]=i\hbar\hat{L}_x$.

Comment: @KrisWalker Got it. If $\hat{L}_x\varphi = L_x\varphi$ and $\hat{L}_y\varphi = L_y\varphi$, then $L_z = 0$, but then using the two latter commutation relations, we can similarly conclude that it must be the case that $L_y = 0$ and $L_x = 0$. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown that you can simultaneously measure all three components if $L_z = 0$. You have shown that *if* you can simultaneously measure $L_x$ and $L_y$, then $L_z = 0$. It isn't generally true that any function with $L_z = 0$ is a simultaneous eigenfunction of $\hat L_x$ and $\hat L_y$, but there is such a function, as you and Tobias Fünke's comment indicate.